# Julia: read CSV into Vector{T} efficiently / type stability

Tags: julia

I have a number of very large CSV files which I would like to parse into custom data structures for subsequent processing. My current approach involves `CSV.File` and then converting each `CSV.Row` into the custom data structure. It works well for small test cases but gets really inefficient for the large files (GC very high). The problem is in the second step and I suspect is due to type instability. I'm providing a mock example below.

(I'm new to Julia, so apologies if I misunderstood something)

Define data structure and conversion logic:

```
using CSV

struct Foo
    a::Int32
    b::Float32
end

Foo(csv_row::CSV.Row) = Foo(csv_row.a, csv_row.b)
```

Using the default constructor causes 0 allocations:

```
julia> @allocated foo1 = Foo(1, 2.5)
0
```

However, when creating the object from `CSV.Row` all of a sudden 80 bytes are allocated:

```
julia> data = CSV.File(Vector{UInt8}("a,b\n1,2.5"); threaded = false)
1-element CSV.File{false}:
 CSV.Row: (a = 1, b = 2.5f0)

julia> @allocated foo2 = Foo(data[1])
80
```

In the first case all types are stable:

```
julia> @code_warntype Foo(1, 2)
Variables
  #self#::Core.Compiler.Const(Foo, false)
  a::Int64
  b::Int64

Body::Foo
1 ─ %1 = Main.Foo::Core.Compiler.Const(Foo, false)
│   %2 = Core.fieldtype(%1, 1)::Core.Compiler.Const(Int32, false)
│   %3 = Base.convert(%2, a)::Int32
│   %4 = Core.fieldtype(%1, 2)::Core.Compiler.Const(Float32, false)
│   %5 = Base.convert(%4, b)::Float32
│   %6 = %new(%1, %3, %5)::Foo
└──      return %6
```

Whereas in the second case they are not:

```
julia> @code_warntype Foo(data[1])
Variables
  #self#::Core.Compiler.Const(Foo, false)
  csv_row::CSV.Row

Body::Foo
1 ─ %1 = Base.getproperty(csv_row, :a)::Any
│   %2 = Base.getproperty(csv_row, :b)::Any
│   %3 = Main.Foo(%1, %2)::Foo
└──      return %3
```

So I guess my question is: How can I make the second case type-stable and avoid the allocations?

Providing the types explicitly in `CSV.File` does not make a difference by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this does not focus on type stability, I would expect the highest performance combined with flexibility from the following code:

```
d = DataFrame!(CSV.File(Vector{UInt8}("a,b\n1,2.5\n3,4.0"); threaded = false))
```

The above efficiently transforms a `CSV.File` into a type stable structure, additionally avoiding data copying in this process. This should work for your case of huge CSV files.

And now:

```
julia> Foo.(d.a, d.b)
2-element Array{Foo,1}:
 Foo(1, 2.5f0)
 Foo(3, 4.0f0)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed much faster. Would still be interesting to understand why there are 80 bytes allocated in the second case compared with 0 in the first.